# What is the path of the Json file in Android at Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

[image]

I am developing an application for Android using Xamarin.
I have created a JsonData folder in the Android project and created a Setting.json file.

```
\MyApp\MyApp.Android\JsonData\Setting.json
```

In the properties, we set the Copy when new.
The following folders in the local environment contain the files.

```
\MyApp\MyApp.Android\bin\Debug\JsonData\Setting.json
```

I want to load this file in the actual Android device.
When I do this, it tells me that the file is missing.

```
Could not find a part of the path "/JsonData/Setting.json."
```

```
Try
{
    var text = File.ReadAllText("JsonData/Setting.json", Encoding.UTF8);
    var setting = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Setting>(text);
}
catch(Exception exception)
{
    var error = exception.Message;
}
```

What is the path of the file in Android?

Comment: what is the build action for the file?

Comment: Can you add the setting file in the Cross Platform project ? if yes i can write the solution and you can read the file from there.

Comment: thank you comment Jason! build action is none.

Comment: Thank you Amja S. Yes I can add the setting file in the Cross Platform project.
Does a Cross Platform project mean a Xamarin.Form project?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using [File Handling in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows) incorrectly.

From the parameter of function `File.ReadAllText`, the app  will  access the file system to get`Setting.json`  from folder `JsonData` in your android device.

The path of the file on each platform can be determined from a .NET Standard library by using a value of the [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=net-6.0) enumeration as the first argument to the `Environment.GetFolderPath` method. This can then be combined with a filename with the Path.Combine method:

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "temp.txt");
```

And you can read the file by  code:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
```

**In addition**, from your code,I guess you want to Load your Embedded file( `Setting.json`)  as Resources,right?

In this case,we should make sure the Build Action of your `Setting.json` is `Embedded Resource`.
[image]

And `GetManifestResourceStream` is used to access the embedded file using its Resource ID.

You can refer to the following code:

```
var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(LoadResourceText)).Assembly;
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("YourAppName.JsonData.Setting.json");
string text = "";
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader (stream))
{  
    text = reader.ReadToEnd ();
}
```

For more , you can check document : [File Handling in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows).

And you can also check the sample code here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/workingwithfiles/ .

Comment: Thank you very much.
There were a number of points.
(1) Place the Json file in the .NET Standard project, not in Android.
(2) Set Embedded Resource in the properties of the Json file.
(3) Use Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData to acquire the folder under the application.
I understood these and was able to read the JSON file.

Comment: Congrats. Thanks for your support for xamarin. :)

Comment: I tried. But failed.
var rootFolderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(
    Path.GetDirectoryName(
     //"/mnt/expand/55555-555-5555-5555-55555555555/user/0/com.companyname.rg2022/files/.local/share"
     Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
     ));
   var fileFullPath = Path.Combine(rootFolderPath, "JsonData/Setting.json");
   var files = Directory.GetFiles(rootFolderPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);//<-this is empty.

Comment: Could  you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?

Comment: https://github.com/misakikaoru/SG2022

Comment: Thanks Jessie. This is github url. Please test it.

Comment: Is your link correct ? I can't see any code for `file. ReadAllText`?

Comment: Sorry I mistake commit. I commit json read code. Please check  https://github.com/misakikaoru/SG2022

Comment: Hi  @kaoru,  is the code up to date? The demo crashed after  deployed to my device.

Comment: Oh!? The demo works in my device. Uhmmmm....

Comment: I updated project. and I add image in my device. Would you please check it.